# Simple SELECT * from ('table_name') fails

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My CI application has a simple model method that does a SELECT all from a particular table.

On my development server, where the table contains about 12,000 records, the call to the model method works fine. On my production server, where the table contains about 67,000+ records currently, the call to the model method fails. It just stops execution. Error log doesn't show anything.

Comment: how does it fail?  what does mysql_error say? does it hang? have you profiled the query to see if it takes longer than max_execution_time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can either be the max_execution time or more likely in this case, it can be the memory_limit. You might be exhausting PHPs memory limit trying to store all those 67K rows in memory.

Comment: JohnP - what's the best way to set max_execution and memory_limit? Can I set it for a particular method only? The script I am trying to execute is creating XML site maps based on what products I have in my database. Each sitemap can contain up to 50K entries (but it has a file size limit, too, so I limit it to 45K per sitemap just in case). I want to run the script once a day, say at 3am when there is not a lot of traffic on the site. Another option is to just query the DB for 9K records at a time, loop 5 times, and get my 45K entries for my sitemap.

Comment: The 9K records at a time idea is not an ideal solution, though, I think. I'll need to open/close files, etc. Would rather do everything in one go.

Comment: you can increase/decrease for only a single method by using ini_set(). You might also want run this as a cron or through CLI and send the memory limit only for that run. See here : http://cristian-radulescu.ro/article/php-cli-increase-memory-limit.html

Answer (score 1):

Max execution time is probably the cause. Increase max_execution_time in your production php.ini file.